# Print commands executed by subprocess.call (subprocess.call trace)

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, debian-jessie

My Pytnon script has a number of methods like:

```
def clean_htmldir(self):
    super(Cov,self).clean0('rm -rf {:s}/*'.format(self.COV_HTMLDIR))
```

where clean0 is a method of the super class

```
def clean0(self, rm_cmd):
    ret = subprocess.call(rm_cmd, shell=True)
    return ret
```

Python script executes a number of shell commands. I'd like to see them on the screen when debugging (seeing them all the time would be tedious). I may complement each of the subprocess.call call with the print statement introducing simultaneously some `global' variable say 'turn_trace_onoff' controlled by command line arguments.

Is there a more conventional and robust (maybe automated) method (w/o duplicating) to do that in Python?

Using Pytnon 2.7 on Debian jessie

PS
`print' solution wouldn't work, it will show no file name expansions which is done by the shell.

PPS
When using bash the command line switch

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

is exact what'd like to get when subprocess.call

Comment: What did you mean by said `I'd like to see them on the screen `? You want to see every file which going to be deleted?

Comment: I want to see on the screen the exact shell commands with file name expansion which is done by shell commands
e.g
rm -rf /home/workspace/Release-910.4.3/cov/report/*
with * substituted with the real file names

Comment: Kind of the behavior we get when use bash -x command line switch